# What exactly am I starting when I launch a pyspark kernel in jupyter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

When I start a pyspark kernel in my juoyter notebook, what exactly is it starting up? A JVM/python/Scala environment just for me? What I don't understand is that many developers login to the same jupyter notebook server in the company and each has his own kernel. So starting one does not affect other kernels used by other developers?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without having access to your environment. Usually it will start Python driver, Py4j gateway and JVM driver.

However, it this is not the possible option. Your notebook can for example use magics to connect to an existing Livy session or communicate with Spark using Toree like solution and messaging queue.